# Erratic behaviour of Haskell Language Server in VSCode

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have the `Haskell` extension installed on Visual Studio Code. This extension downloaded and installed Haskell Language Server and, for no apparent reason, sometimes it works perfectly fine and sometimes it doesn't.

When it does work, the extension is able to react to live changes in the code, highlighting all kinds of errors, warnings, etc, and displaying function documentation on the fly. Perfect stuff.

However, when it does not work, it keeps highlighting the first line of each module's file as an error, mentioning that:

```
Multi Cradle: No prefixes matched
pwd: /Users/jivan/haskell-descriptions
filepath: /Users/jivan/haskell-descriptions/src/Proceed.hs
prefixes:
("./src/Main.hs",Stack {component = Just "haskell-descriptions:exe:descriptions", stackYaml = Nothing})
```

The content of `hie.yaml` is the following:

```yaml
cradle:
  multi:
    - path: "./"
      config:
        cradle:
          stack:
            - path: "./src/Main.hs"
              component: "haskell-descriptions:exe:descriptions"
```

It actually used to work *without* the `component` part in `hie.yaml`, however now I can't get it to work again, whether the `component` part is here or not.

I was told about `gen-hie` but no way to make it run successfully, as when I type `gen-hie` in a terminal, all I get as an answer is `command not found: gen-hie` (despite it being declared in both `stack.yaml` and `.cabal` files).

Any idea or suggestions welcome.

Comment: I know this question is old, but for anyone searching at least the last part of the question can be solved with `stack install gen-hie` and ensuring `~/.local/bin` (if I'm not mistaken) is on your path.